# NoMethodError - undefined method - ruby on rails - collection select dropdown

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select, collections, dropdown

Im trying to do a drop down select box on ruby on rails but encounter the error below

error

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `typename' for {"typename"=>"dasds"}:Hash:
```

view

```
  = f.input :visitortype, collection: @visitor_types_collection, label_method: 'typename', include_blank: false, required: true, class:"form-control"
```

controller (whats wrong with this>)

```
  @visitor_types_collection = [{"typename" => "dasds"}]
```

For Your Info, I am actually trying to put this in (the sample above is just to get some idea how its done):

```
{"visitor_types" => [{"typename" => "Friend",
                         "require_mgmt_approval" => "false"},
                        {"typename" => "Delivery",
                         "require_mgmt_approval" => "true"},
                        {"typename" => "Contractor",
                         "require_mgmt_approval" => "true"}
                        ]}
```

Comment: Please use map here

Comment: how to assign map @visitor_types_collection

Comment: Sorry I mean use select here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please try with key value format like this:

In controller:

```
 @visitor_types_collection = [['Option1','Value1'],['Option2','Value2']]



= f.select :visitortype, collection: @visitor_types_collection, label_method: 'typename', include_blank: false, required: true, class:"form-control"
```

Comment: has error: undefined method `map' for false:FalseClass

Comment: I have updated code, please try and let me know if it work for you?

Comment: still with the same error: NoMethodError - undefined method `map' for false:FalseClass:

Comment: I have not used map anywhere so how could the error same. please restart if in production mode and show complete error trace.

Comment: still the same. i removed some other false and true params, it doesnt complain but not the drop down i want. = f.select :visitortype, collection: @visitor_types_collection, label_method: 'typename'

Comment: can you try once: f.select :visitortype, [['horrible', 1], ['poor', 2], ['mediocre', 3], ['good', 4], ['great', 5]]

Comment: it works, but the view with f.select is different than f.input http://imgur.com/ysb6fGY

Comment: this basically work. got a question, do you know of to select the default selection ? = f.input :visitortype, label: "Visitor category", collection: @visitor_types_collection.map {|obj| obj["typename"]}, include_blank: false, required: true, class:"form-control"

Comment: You have to use value by default that should be present, use a blank option in array ['Please select', ''] like that